# Rewrite in .htaccess (URL with parameter)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

At the moment I'm not really good in unterstanding how URL Rewrite in htaccess works (with regEex).

I want to have following Url:

```
example.org/lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-1/
```

It should go to following Url with the number at the at as parameter:

```
example.org/index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=1
```

I have tried different ways but they all dont work. The last I have tried was:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-([0-9]+)\$ index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=$1 [L}
```

This one made problems on the whole website. every page was inaccessible.

Can someone show me a Rewrite Rule that works in my case and explain the RegEx in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some typos in your rule. Try it this way.

```
RewriteRule ^lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=$1 [L]
```

Note that I used the `?` after the `/` so that it can be optional. You had a backslash. Also at the end of your rule you had a curly brace instead of the bracket.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment. Then you can use this if part of the URI is not constant.

```
RewriteRule ^lyrik/kategorien/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=$2 [L]
```

Also this `[0-9]+` just means it has to be a number from 0-9 to match the rule and the plus sign means 1 or more basically saying it can't be empty. The `*` basically means any including a blank(0 or more occurrences). Because your link always ends with a number limiting it to 0-9 in the regex ensures that it won't work if any other character is used there in the URL.

You can see more about regex here.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: it is working! thank you! but i have one more problem:
the word "allgemein" should be variable. its just for the name of the categorie and only the number after (the ID) should count.
so example.org/lyrik/kategorien/foobar-1/ should go to the same site

Comment: See my updated answer there if it should be a variable. Let me know how that works.

Comment: with your new solution the word before the id ("allgemein") is given in the get parameter (kategorienId) where the id should be. EDIT: now i have simply replaced $1 with $2 and now the id is correctly given to the get parameter: "RewriteRule ^lyrik/kategorien/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=$2 [L]"

Comment: Yes I forgot to change that part. Sorry. I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: thank you again! in which way i need the [QSA] (as Alexandru Godri said in the other response) for other parameters?

Comment: You don't need the `QSA` flag in this situation. What it does is append any  query you have on the URL to your rewrite. So it will only be helpful if you URL is like this `http://example.org/lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-1/?somestring=something` then it will also send `somestring=something` in addition to your rewriterule.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-(.*?)/$ index.php?seite=kategorienDetail&kategorienId=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am writing from the top of my head, but it should work. Let me know if it doesn't, but it should :)

Edit: Please add the QSA flag also to pass any other query parameters you might have.

Alex

Comment: your method also works. thank you! but the word "allgemein" should be variable (see answer on Paname Jacks response above.
example.org/lyrik/kategorien/foobar-1/ or any other word instead of foobar should go to the same site.

and can some of you explain the difference between:
^lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-([0-9]+)/?$
and
^lyrik/kategorien/allgemein-(.*?)/$